# Blank app when launching a windows form with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am creating an interface for monitoring using C# in Visual Studio 2022. I wrote a simple code with a primal design when I build there are no errors or warnings - everything is good. But when I launch the app, its main form appears BLANK - just a white window with nothing in it.

This is the project folder:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1289L4kocyYrBW9FGasU6Dhxs9r1vEHN7/view?usp=sharing

Please help me - it's for a school project.

Thank you

I tried all possible solution and checked all settings and still the same problem although the codes show no errors or warnings

Comment: Please [edit] your post with a [mre]. It's not right to put a link to a download location for your code, nor post your _entire_ codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Form1 class is in it's own namespace called `PowerConsumptionMonitor`, and the startup code isn't referencing it properly. Modify this line in your `Program.cs` file:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to

```
Application.Run(new PowerConsumptionMonitor.Form1());
```